# Can Java Serialization deserialize objects as an instance of a parent class

Tags: java, serialization

I have a base class that implements `Serializable`.

```
class Base implements Serializable { 
    ... //some fields
}
```

Also I have another class that extends the base class.

```
class Another extends Base { 
    ... //some fields
}
```

I have a serialized instance of `Another`. Can I deserialize it as instance of `Base`?

Comment: How do you serialize and deserialize them?

Comment: Yes, you can serialize `Access` and then deserialize as `Base`, but you will lose all `Access`-specific data.

Comment: @LuisG. I think depending on serialization/deserialization method / framework this will change. For sure, as per hierarchy in question, you can deserialize `Another` and then cast to to `Base` class. But deserialize directly `Base` without involving `Another` normally should be problematic, if it is not a `json` or some relaxed format.

Comment: You can use `readResolve` if you actually need the deserialised instance to have a runtime class of `Base` or any other class. / In general classes should be either `abstract` of effectively `final`.

Comment: @walen No you won't. Where did you get that idea?

Comment: XY problem. Why do you think you need to do this?

Comment: @user207421 Replied to your comment on my answer.

Comment: @waken No you didn't. You just restated your false idea. Object slicing does not happen in Java.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Yes, in general you can do so.

Simplest example ignoring stream initialization, closing, exceptions, etc.

```
class Base implements Serializable { 
    String a;
    Base(String a) { this.a = a; }
}
class Another extends Base { 
    String b;
    Another(String a, String b) { super(a); this.b = b; }
}
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Another another = new Another("string1", "string2");
        // Serialization  
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(...);
        out.writeObject(access);
        // Deserialization 
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(...);
        Base base = (Base) in.readObject();
        System.out.println("Base.a = " + base.a); // ok, prints "string1"
        // System.out.println("Another.b = " + base.b); // -> compilation error -- this is not an Another object; "string2" has not been deserialized.
    }
}
```

However, there's little reason to do this. You can always deserialize as `Another` to get all the data, and then cast to `Base` as needed.

Comment: if parent instance is deserialized under the subclass name, it won't be a problem right?

Comment: @RNanthak You mean serializing a `Base` instance and then deserializing it as an `Another` instance? Of course it **will** be a problem. Child classes can replace their parent class, but the contrary is not necessarily true. Classic "every `Dog` is an `Animal`, but not every `Animal` is a `Dog`". You can try yourself: take my code, change it so `writeObject()` takes a `Base` instance instead of an `Another` instance, and then try to read it as `(Another) in.readObject()`. You will get a `ClassCastException: Base cannot be cast to Another` error.

Comment: The deserialized object remains an instance of `Another`. You just temporarily lose sight of that via the cast. However any overridden methods will still be called. Answer is not correct.

Comment: @walen yes you are correct, its not working

Comment: @user207421 As long as you use the deserialized object as a `Base` instance, you won't be able to access `Another` fields or methods. Which is why my answer literally recommends to "deserialize as `Another` to get all the data, and then cast to `Base` as needed". I think this is what you mean, i.e., the serialized object has all of `Another` data (of course -- it _is_  an `Another` object, after all). But as long as you deserialize it to a `Base` instance, `Base` fields and methods are the only thing you will see (unless you cast it back to `Another`, of course).

Comment: @wallen That is not correct. The overridden methods continue to be called. This is rather basic. Merely downcasting a reference does not change the underlying object.

Comment: @user207421 Yes, you're right that overriden methods would use `Another`'s implementation, but that may be looking too much into it. The OP didn't mention any overriden methods, just a couple classes with "some fields"; so I took OP's question to mean "can I serialize an `Another` object with some fields and then deserialize and use it as its parent class `Base`?" -- and the answer to this is still "generally yes". However, it _is_ true that there are cases where the deserialized object won't behave as a `Base` instance. **Would you like me to edit my answer, or are you writing your own?**

Comment: You should correct your answer regardless of what else happens, but it would involve changing the first word from 'yes' to 'no' and correspondingly throughout.